# Как получить всех пользователей с bool true?

Tags: phpmyadmin, redbeanphp

Хочу воспользоваться findLike в phph red bean. И хочу получить несколько значений из базы данных. Вот например база данных.

| Id | name | bool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | false |
| 2 | name2 | true |
| 3 | name3 | true |

И мне надо получить всех пользователей с bool true и когда я это делаю получаю результат в массив. Когда я это делаю у меня происходит следующее.
1 индекс будет пуст, 2 индекс будет содержать 2 пользователя, 3 тоже самое. Я знаю, что 1 индекс пуст из-за того, что в Id 1 содержит false.

Как сделать так чтобы я получал только тех у кого true. То есть я получал массив такой 1(id:2, name:name2, bool:true) 2(id:3, name:name3, bool:true)

Comment: Если что вот эти не понятные строчки и Id name и bool я хотел сделать столбец

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE bool = true
```

table - это таблица, измените её свою.